# Route not found error in Laravel 4 with form on Home page

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have made a form on home page in *hello.blade.php* file , with form value

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'home/addguest', 
                        'class' => "form-horizontal")) }}
```

I have defined a method named `addGuest()` in `HomeController` which adds values in database and sends email.

I am getting error on home page as

```
ErrorException

Route [home/addguest] not defined. (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/hello.blade.php)
```

Route.php has

```
Route::post('Home/addGuest', array('uses' => 'HomeController@addGuest'));

Route::get('/home', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

What value shall I define in form attribute to post this data and save that in the database?
Shall I change the form post target or shall I change the `homecontroller` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In route.php

```
Route::post('Home/addGuest', array('uses' => 'HomeController@addGuest'));
```

Should be

```
Route::post('Home/addGuest', array('as' => 'addguest', 'uses' => 'HomeController@addGuest'));
```

The "as" is the naming of the route, that you are refering to in the form. Be sure to update the Forms route to just "addguest" as well.

Comment: Jimmie, I tried your route but still its not working, it says route not defined!!
I am using this form on the home page only and haven't created any controller/route. Do I need that??

Comment: Well, you need the HomeController with a method called addGuest which you say you have. And this should be a route in the routes.php. Try maybe name it without a slash. Like 'as' => 'addguest' and do the same thing in your form-code 'route' => 'addguest'.

Comment: Hmm one weird thing tho. You say this code is in hello.blade.php? Then you reference a view named home. That should probably be View::make('hello')